# ANGULAR - How to properly handle multilevel JSON responses?

Tags: json, angular, multidimensional-array, data-binding, angular2-observables

I am using a rest API, sending a GET request and getting the following JSON structure as a result:

```
{
  "Id": "Sample Id",
  "Attributes": {
    "ReadOnly": false
  },
  "Children": [
    {
      "Id": "Sample Id1",
      "Attributes": {
        "ReadOnly": false
      },
      "Children": [
        {
          "Id": "Sample Id2",
          "Attributes": {
            "ReadOnly": false
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": "Sample Name2",
      "Attributes": {
        "ReadOnly": false
      },
      "Children": [
        {
          "Id": "Sample Id2",
          "Attributes": {
            "ReadOnly": false
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It is basically a file system structure. So it is possible to have N objects(Id, Attributes{}, Children[]) in the root as well as in any other level of the structure.

Trying to explain a little bit better, the root node has its attributes and an array of N children that have its attributes and another Array of N children and so on...

How would be the correct way to handle this situation?

I have created a flat interface structure, looking basically like that:

```
 export interface Hana{
      Id: string,
      Attributes: {
        ReadOnly: string
      }
    }
```

I have also created a service and a component  as follows:

**Service**

```
  getHanaStructure(): Observable<Hana[]> {
    const hanaStructs = this.http.get<Hana[]>(this.apiUrl);
    this.messageService.add('HanaService: fetched struct');
    return hanaStructs;
```

**Component**

```
  hanaStructures$: Observable<Hana[]>;

  getHanaStructure() : void {
     this.hanaStructures$ = this.hanaService.getHanaStructure().pipe(map(data=> _.toArray(data)));
  }
```

In order to show the data my HTML template looks like that:

```
  <ul *ngIf="hanaStructures$ | async as hanaStructures else noData">
          <li *ngFor="let hana of hanaStructures">
              {{hana}}
          </li> 
      </ul>
      <ng-template #noData>No Data Available</ng-template>
```

The first problem is that I don't know to access the information by its key, I can just list their values. When I try something like **{{ hana.Id }}** instead of just **{{ hana }}** I got: *

> "Property 'Id' does not exist on type 'Hana'"

- 

The second issue is that I can only manage to list the first level data. I don´t know how access the Children of the Children of Children...

I am sure that the API is returning everything I need, but unfortunately  I don´t know how to solve the problem.

Thanks,

Filipe

Answer (score 0):

At first I would define the "Children" property in your Hana Interface as List of "Hana" Interfaces (This has some similarity with a resursive approach). Afterwards I would create a seperate Component, which gets displayed if you loop through the first layer of your children. This component should contain a loop of its own to loop through deeper nested components recursively.
Hope this was understandable and helps you. =)